# how to map RDD of strings to columns of a Dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD of string which stores the column names of a dataframe. I'd like to map each value of this RDD to count of column it refers to. Here is my code:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(features)
mis = rdd.map(lambda x: df.select(x).distinct.count())
```

It gives me the following error message

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 201, in __repr__
return self._jrdd.toString()
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2379, in _jrdd
pickled_cmd, bvars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(self.ctx, command, self)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2299, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
...
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o183.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is wrong?

`features` is a list. One possible solution is to keep `features` as a list and do something like below

```
mis = map(lambda x: df.select(x).distinct.count(),features)
```

This solution works, but it calculates the distinct count for each feature one by one. What I'm trying to achieve is to calculate the distinct count on all the feature in parallel, not one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a RDD or DF in method of RDD or DF.

Your solution is the best approach. Other example is:

```
mis = []
for x in rdd.collect() :
    mis.append(df.select(x).distinct.count())
```

Regards.